# Instantiating 4 bit Full Adder

Tags: vhdl, instantiation

I'm having difficulty instantiating the fa0 portion of this code. I'm fairly new to VHDL so maybe more than just an answer would help.

This Logic 4 Module is structural code as a component to an ALU that I'm working on.

Thank you

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 4-bit adder/subtractor module
-----------------------------------------------------------------
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity addsub4 is
    port (addl_subh : in std_logic;
        X, Y      : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        S         : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        cout, ovf : out std_logic);
end addsub4;

architecture addsub4_arch of addsub4 is

    component fa is
        port (cin, x, y : in std_logic;
            s, cout   : out std_logic);
    end component fa;

    -- let Yhat denote the signal after Y xor addl_subh
    signal Yhat: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); 
    -- let carryout denote the cout signal for each fa module
    signal carryout: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); 

begin

    Yhat(0) <= Y(0) xor addl_subh;
    Yhat(1) <= Y(1) xor addl_subh;
    Yhat(2) <= Y(2) xor addl_subh;
    Yhat(3) <= Y(3) xor addl_subh;

    fa0: fa
        port map ( cin => addl_subh, x => X(0), y => Yhat(0),
                s => S(0), cout => carryout(0));

    fa1: fa
        port map ( cin => carryout(0), x => X(1), y => Yhat(1),
                 s => S(1), cout => carryout(1));

    fa2: fa
        port map ( cin => carryout(1), x => X(2), y => Yhat(2),
                 s => S(2), cout => carryout(2));

    fa3: fa
        port map ( cin => carryout(2), x => X(3), y => Yhat(3),
                 s => S(3), cout => carryout(3));

    cout <= carryout(3);
    ovf <= carryout(2) xor carryout(3);

end addsub4_arch;
```

Comment: instance: A subcomponent of a design entity whose prototype is a component declaration, design entity, or configuration declaration.  You have four instances of entity fa, of which one is decorated with the label fa0.  Noting your code analyzes, your question isn't clear.  Are you having trouble writing the entity fa and it's architecture?  Are you having trouble elaborating addsub4?

Comment: I am confused with all of this but I suppose my question is geared to writing the entity of the fa and it's architecture.

I'm in a course titled Digital Logic Design but we don't sit down and discuss coding for VHDL. Most of this code is code I pieced together from different sites including code my professor gave me.

To help me, I'm creating this 4 bit module, would that be the reason why I have four instances of fa?

Comment: Perhaps you need the right introduction, for instance Peter Ashenden's [VHDL Tutorial](http://hep.uchicago.edu/~tangjian/SVT_sub/FTK_ATLAS/AUX/vhdl-tutorial.pdf). It's 82 pages, you can skim then focus on chapter 4 'Basic Modeling Concepts'. You aren't presenting a specific programming question and your question might get down voted.

Comment: Okay, Thank you! Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

your code has no errors and you should add a seperate file to your project that contains the fa (full adder) code. for example :

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY fa IS
PORT(x,y,cin : IN std_logic;
     s,cout  : OUT std_logic);
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE dataflow OF fa IS
begin
    s <= x xor y xor cin;
    cout <= ((x xor y) and cin) or (x and y);
end dataflow;
```